# todonotes: how to hide certain entries from list of todos?

Tags: todonotes

I'd like to handle some todos differently than others by defining a new command for them that makes them hidden in the list of todos. Just setting the caption to empty does not suffice (the entry remains just without any text beside the ellipsis and page number).

NWME:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{todonotes}
\presetkeys{todonotes}{inline}{}
\newcommand\todohidden[2][]{%
    \todo[inline, caption={}, #1]{%
        #2%
    }%
}

\begin{document}

\listoftodos

\vspace{0.5\textheight}
\todo{Normal todo}
\todohidden{Hidden todo}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The package doc says: `\todo[nolist]{}` will do.

Comment: Indeed, I missed that :( If you simply re-post the MWE with the `caption` keyval replaced with `nolist` I am happy to accept it as answer :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `todonotes` package provides the option `nolist` for the `\todo` command which will hide the note from the list of todos (see package documentation, page 6):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{todonotes}
\presetkeys{todonotes}{inline}{}
\newcommand\todohidden[2][]{%
    \todo[inline, nolist, #1]{%
        #2%
    }%
}

\begin{document}

\listoftodos

\vspace{0.5\textheight}
\todo{Normal todo}
\todohidden{Hidden todo}

\end{document}
```